# Will it work if I set up a http/ssh/ftp server on my android phone using the cellular mobile network?

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-network, ssh, web-server

I can set up a ssh server on my android phone, by running SSH Server by Ice Code App on my Android 4.4.2 phone over my home WiFi network. So my laptop can access the my phone via ssh in the same WiFi network.

When there is no wifi, can I do the same to set up a ssh server on my android phone over my carrier's cellular mobile network? Is there some difference between the setup over a WiFI and setup over a cellular mobile network?

How about http and ftp servers?

Answer (score 2):

That entirely depends on your carrier's setup. For security reasons, several carriers (not all) block the required ports for incoming connections – so though your setup theoretically runs fine, you can't reach your services as the carrier blocks access.

I have not tried it, but in that case it *might* be possible working around using a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) (some apps for that purpose can be found [in my app list](https://android.izzysoft.de/catmin/applists/category/named/network_vpn)); a VPN should tunnel those requests to your device then. Again: I've not tested this, so it might or might not work.

Answer (score 1):

It should be the same since you need a unique public ip either way (using wifi, lte or 3g).

Comment: Thanks. If I set up a server over a mobile network, will I get a public ip uniquely for my phone, not shared with other devices?

Comment: You should but you cant portforward

Comment: what do you mean by "portforward" here?

Comment: You didnt portforward while on wifi?